# Doctrine 2: Update Entity Using Table Schema

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using doctrine 2 within zend framework 2. To generate methods from existing entities using database table, the console command used is:

```
php doctrine-module orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" --generate-methods="true" module
```

I have two namespaces Blog and Location

My question is:

```
 1. When I run above code, only blog entities get updated. I want to know why it is behaving like this?
 2. If I want to update only a specific entity, how can i do it?
```

The blog has two entities: Post and cateogry

Category.php

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Categories")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
    * Get Id
    *
    * @param integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * Set name
    *
    * @param string $name
    * @return Category
    */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get name
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

Post.php

```
namespace Blog\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="posts")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_date", type="datetime", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $createdDate;

    /**
     * @var \Blog\Entity\Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Blog\Entity\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $category;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @param string $content
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get content
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdDate
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setCreatedDate($createdDate)
    {
        $this->createdDate = $createdDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedDate()
    {
        return $this->createdDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \Blog\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setCategory(\Blog\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \Blog\Entity\Category 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

The Location has Country.php

```
<?php
namespace Country\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="countries")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=55, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;


}
```

Comment: can you post blog and Location entity mappings?

Answer (score 0):

OF Course everyone need a function on ZF2 that's turns to possible you generate a single entity. but those times you can't do it just by doctrine-orm-module. When you try to run doctrine in Symphony it's acceptable. I'm using doctrine2 with zf2 having the same issue.

I create a PHP Script that I call

```
Script to Create a Single Entity:
Choose Entity Name.
Generate All Entities on a Temp Folder.
Exclude All non-needed entities from folder.
Copy Single Entity to "src/$module/Entity" Folder.
```

Is a hack that i got to make it work property as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the --filter option to do this.
php doctrine-module orm:generate-entities --filter="Post" ...